# Move semantics and overload

Tags: c++, overloading, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I think my understanding of rvalue references and move semantics has some holes in it.

As far as I've rvalue references understood now, I could implement a function `f` in two ways such that it profits from move semantics.

*The first version*: implement both

```cpp
void f(const T& t);
void f(T&& t);
```

This would result in quite some redundancy, as both versions are likely to have (almost) identical implementation.

*second version*: implement only

```cpp
void f(T t);
```

Calling `f` would result in calling either the copy or the move constructor of `T`.

*Question.*
How do the two versions compare to each other? My suspicion:
In the second version, (ownership of) dynamically allocated data may be moved by the move constructor, while non-dynamically allocated data in `t` and its members needs to be copied. In the first version, neither version allocates any additional memory (except the pointer behind the reference).

If this is correct, can I avoid writing the implementation of `f` basically twice without the drawback of the second version?

Comment: you can make it call another. so you don't really need to write identical code.

Comment: and which is better would depend on what these function actually does.

Comment: @appleapple In what case what would be better?

Comment: @ Bubaya basically one make a copy and one doesn't. fwiw, actually they're not even semantically equal, for example, the copy cannot modify the source object.

Comment: _What the functions actually do_ seem to be very relevant to your question.  We can not discuss whether copies need to happen or what memory needs to be allocated by only looking at these function declarations.  Whether you even need two versions of this function depends on what the function does.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where you'd want both `T&` and `T&&` overloads. Did you mean to write `T const&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to take a `T&&` parameter, it usually means you want to move the object somewhere and keep it. This kind of function is typically paired up with a `const T&` overload so it can accept both rvalues and lvalues.

In this situation, the second version (only one overload with `T` as a parameter) is always less efficient, but most likely not by much.

With the first version, if you pass an lvalue, the function takes a reference and then makes a copy to store it somewhere. That's one copy construction or assignment. If you pass an rvalue, the function again takes a reference and then moves the object to store it. That's one move construction or assignment.

With the second version, if you pass an lvalue, it gets copied into the parameter, and then the function can move that. If you pass an rvalue, if gets moved (assuming the type has a move constructor) into the parameter, and then the function can also move that. In both cases, that's one more move construction or assignment than with the first version.

Also note that [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) can happen in some cases.

The benefit of the second version is that you don't need multiple overloads. With the first version, you need 2^n overloads for n parameters that you need copied or moved.

In the simple case of just one parameter, I sometimes do something like this to avoid repeating code:

```
void f(const T& t) {
    f_impl(t);
}
void f(T&& t) {
    f_impl(std::move(t));
}

// this function is private or just inaccessible to the user
template<typename U>
void f_impl(U&& t) {
    // use std::forward<U>(t)
}
```